# How to distinguish between a class and function

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Is there a way to distinguish between a class (not its instance!) and a function in TypeScript during runtime.

Normally classes in typescript are transpiled to javascript functions and during runtime I could not find a nice way to check whether an identifier is a function or a class type!

For example:

```js
function func1() {
 
}

class class1 {
 
}

// ugly hack
(<any>class1.prototype).isclass = true;

// ugly hack test
function is_class(clazz:any) {
 return (
  clazz 
  && clazz.prototype 
  && (<any>clazz.prototype).isclass === true
 );
}

console.log(typeof(func1) === 'function'); // returns true !!
console.log(typeof(class1) === 'function'); // returns true !!

console.log(is_class(func1)); // returns false :)
console.log(is_class(class1)); // returns true :)
```

Any ideas for a better solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it *definitively* but you can use a heuristic, as `class` methods generally go on `prototype` so:

```
class Foo {
   foo(){}
} 
function foo(){}
console.log(!!Object.keys(Foo.prototype).length); // true : is class 
console.log(!!Object.keys(foo.prototype).length); // false : is not a class
```

Comment: This looks like a cleaner solution. I have to run both through my unit tests and see the result. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

No, not when targeting ES5 or below. Classes are functions as can be seen in the compiled JavaScript:

```
var class1 = (function () {
    function class1() {
    }
    return class1;
}());
```

However, if you are targeting ES6 then you can tell. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760236/188246).

That said, you can create a class that all other classes inherit from:

```
class BaseClass {
    static isClass = true;
}

class Class1 extends BaseClass {

}

console.log(Class1.isClass); // true
```

Comment: Thanks, I came tot the  same conclusion  and your  answer confirms that