# Check if a value is a class?

Tags: javascript, class

Now that classes are in ES6+, I'd like to be able to check if a value is a regular function or a class definition, something like:

```
console.log(isClass(class A {}), 'should be true')
console.log(isClass(class B {}), 'should be true')
console.log(isClass(function () {}), 'should be false')
```

However, I can't seem to find any ways of figuring this out. I've thought of using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(class A {})` as well as `(class A {}).__proto__ === Function.prototype` however they return `true` for functions as well.

So far the best I've come up with is:

```
function isClass (thing) {
    return typeof thing === 'function' && Object.getOwnPropertyNames(thing).indexOf('arguments') === -1
}
```

But that doesn't seem that robust.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758961/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-es6-class-declaration  or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093396/how-do-you-check-the-difference-between-an-ecmascript-6-class-and-function

Comment: thanks, duplicate of the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the compiled code generated by [Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20A%7B%7D), I think there is no way you can tell if a function is used as a class. Back in the time, JavaScript didn't have classes, and every constructor was just a function. Today's JavaScript class keyword don't introduce a new concept of 'classes', it's rather a syntax sugar.

ES6 code:

```
// ES6
class A{}
```

ES5 generated by [Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20A%7B%7D):

```
// ES5
"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var A = function A() {
    _classCallCheck(this, A);
};
```

Of course, if you are into coding conventions, you could parse the function (the class), and check if it's name starts with a capital letter.

```
function isClass(fn) {
    return typeof fn === 'function' && /^(class|function [A-Z])/.test(fn);
}
```

EDIT:

Browsers which already support the class keyword can use it when parsing. Otherwise, you are stuck with the capital letter one.

Comment: That's pretty nifty, turns out my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29093396/130638 would be cool to see your answer over there too.